# python loop wont loop back

Tags: python, loops

hi I'm doing the number guessing game for school. the code repeats "too high/too low" when i picked a different number and sometimes even to 0, still wont show me the correct answer. do you know why?

````
counter=0

while counter<=10:
    counter+=1
    if counter==10:
        print('too many guesses try again')
        break
    
elif guess>rand_num:
        int(input('too high, try again:'))

    elif guess<rand_num:
        int(input('too low try again:'))

    elif rand_num==guess:
        print('Congratations you got it in', counter, 'guesses')
        break

    else:
        print('something went wrong try to fix the code')```
````

Comment: Your missing some code here. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Still missing code, and indentation is wrong.  Make script that reproduces your issue with minimal code, then cut-n-paste it *exactly* into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't assigning the value to the `guess` variable

```py
elif guess>rand_num:
    guess = int(input('too high, try again:'))

elif guess<rand_num:
    guess = int(input('too low try again:'))

elif rand_num==guess:
    guess = print('Congratations you got it in', counter, 'guesses')
    break

else:
    print('something went wrong try to fix the code')'
```

Comment: the code "guess" is there- just above outside the loop. it is guess=int(input('guess a number:'))

Comment: @JocelynBlackwell Make a [mcve].  Include *all* the code to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
import random
import math
# Taking Inputs
lower = int(input("Enter Lower bound:- "))
 
# Taking Inputs
upper = int(input("Enter Upper bound:- "))
 
# generating random number between
# the lower and upper
x = random.randint(lower, upper)
print("\n\tYou've only ", 
       round(math.log(upper - lower + 1, 2)),
      " chances to guess the integer!\n")
 
# Initializing the number of guesses.
count = 0
 
# for calculation of minimum number of
# guesses depends upon range
while count < math.log(upper - lower + 1, 2):
    count += 1
 
    # taking guessing number as input
    guess = int(input("Guess a number:- "))
 
    # Condition testing
    if x == guess:
        print("Congratulations you did it in ",
              count, " try")
        # Once guessed, loop will break
        break
    elif x > guess:
        print("You guessed too small!")
    elif x < guess:
        print("You Guessed too high!")
 
# If Guessing is more than required guesses,
# shows this output.
if count >= math.log(upper - lower + 1, 2):
    print("\nThe number is %d" % x)
    print("\tBetter Luck Next time!")
```